# Xcode 5 gives warning about strlen() in first function only. Bug?

Tags: xcode

I ran into this by accident. In Xcode 5 (untested in other versions), if the first function in a C file contains any calls to `strlen()`, it gives me the warning `Implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char*)'`. But it doesn't give me the warning if I use `strlen` in any of my other functions. So I've been forced to create a throwaway function at the top of one of my files just because I'm afraid of what it will do otherwise. Is there a bug, or am I goofing up somehow?

Here is a screenshot. Notice the warning in test() but not main():
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add

> ```
>  #include <string.h>
> ```

To the top of your file.

Without it, the first time in a file that your compiler sees a function, it will assume that it was defined using very old C style parameters.  There's a lot of background on how this will or won't work, but that's probably more suited to stack overflow.

In general, if you have a C function and want to see what you need to #include to use it, you can do `man strlen` at the terminal.

Comment: That fixes it, but I don't see why it works in the second function but not the first.

Comment: Because it's a one-time-per-file warning.The first time the compiler sees the function, it keeps track of the assumed definition in an internal table and uses it for the rest of the file.